# Small RGB chip identification

Tags: led, rgb

I seem to be struggling in locating a replacement set of LEDs for my DRL board.

The manufacture is in China and will not help me out[image]

The led is an RGB chip but every replacement I have found so far only offers 1 red, 1 green and 1 blue diode, where as these appear to run 3 of each providing more light output but in the same size dimensions.. could it be they have custom made these rather than them being available on the market?

I did consider a COB led however even the smallest of those are far too big

Comment: Without knowing the electrical pin-out, this may be impossible to answer. For example some RGB LED's use common anode, common cathode, individual LED's, I2C control, SPI, etc. Then you have various specs like voltage ratings to consider.

Comment: Crop the photo, man. Crop the photo! > 80% of it is irrelevant. Measure the voltage drop across each when lit. That will tell us if there are three in series for each colour.

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/seoul-semiconductor-inc/F50360/2181973  stock  . did it get hot?

Comment: 3x3 LED 12V board. good ruck. go Ledstrip instead

Comment: Is there something in particular about this board that you like? is it part of a projector or other specific form factor device that matters to you?  It's a rather large, awkward board for just a single high power LED.  DRL as in daytime running lamp?